# Installing Haskell packages through Nix

Tags: haskell, installation, nix, haste

Specifically, I'm trying to install [Haste](https://github.com/valderman/haste-compiler) through [`nix`](http://nixos.org/nix/).

I can see a `hasteCompiler` entry in `nixpkgs/pkgs/top-level/haskell-packages.nix`, and the appropriate `.nix` file in `nixpkgs/pkgs/development/libraries/haskell/haste-compiler/` but I'm not sure how to install it. Specifically, none of

```
nix-env -i haste
nix-env -i haste-compiler
nix-env -i haskell-haste-compiler
```

do what I want, and `nix-env -qa` doesn't list anything containing the substring `haste` as an available package.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

haste-compiler is marked "broken":

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/commit/37b1a0b79abd1d02d5618417b951cf02ef4f6a49

To override, put this in your `.nixpkgs/config.nix`:

`allowBroken = true;`

Comment: Try it out; see what happens.

Comment: Hm. It installs, then complains that it isn't booted, then fails with a cryptic error code when I try to boot it. That's a different problem though.